# Nested Listview

Tags: javascript, web-services, jquery, jquery-mobile

This is my SOAP XML response from my webservice. I want to put(code,name,category and yield) this to 
listview in jquery mobile ,Im using Icenium (html,css,js,jquery mobile framework). and also count all the table so Ican put in a Badge notification. thanks!! i hope you can help me

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Code" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Keywords" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Category" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Yield" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="YieldUnit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">

<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<Code>106377</Code>
<Name>Blackened red snapper</Name>
<Category>123</Category>
<Yield>4</Yield>
<YieldUnit/>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<Code>303570</Code>
<Name>Celery soup</Name>
<Category>123</Category>
<Yield>1</Yield>
<YieldUnit/>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<Code>303675</Code>
<Name>Challah French Toast</Name>
<Category>123</Category>
<Yield>6</Yield>
<YieldUnit/>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
<Code>303681</Code>
<Name>Challah french toast</Name>
<Category>123</Category>
<Yield>4</Yield>
<YieldUnit/>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
<Code>303744</Code>
<Name>Chana dhal (or dal)</Name>
<Category>123</Category>
<Yield>6</Yield>
<YieldUnit/>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

My codes in Html

```
   <div class="article">


                    <h1>List Of Recipes</h1>

                    <ul id="RecipeList" data-inset="true">
                        </ul>

            </div><!-- /article -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things you need to do.
First, get an XML response from server using $.ajax() call from jQuery.
Second. Parse the xml response and find the data you need with a code like this:

```
var xmlText = $(xml).find("soap\\:Envelope").find("soap\\:Body").find("getPurseBalanceResponse").find("getPurseBalanceResult").find("balance").text();
console.log(xmlText);
```

Next, once parse, the obtained data can be appended to your listview using jquery append() method.

Comment: This is my Codes in conecting to service

Comment: $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: RecpLt,
                            contentType: "text/xml",
                            dataType: "xml",
                            data: ConnRequest,
                            success: GetRecpSuccess,
                          });

Comment: This is my code in GetRecpSuccess to get and put in the listview but there something wrong in my codes. It put in the List view like this.: Code :106377303570303675303681303744

Comment: function GetRecpSuccess(req){
        $(req.responseText).find('GetRecipeListResult').each(function(){ 
                      var Code =   $(this).find('Code').text()            
                         var Name = $(this).find('Name').text()  
                         var Category = $(this).find('Category').text()   
                   $("#RecipeList").append('<li><h3>'  + '</h3><ul><li>Code: '+ Code + '</li><li>Name: '+ Name + '</li><li>Category: '+ Category + '</li></ul></li>');  
                  });       
          }